# SQLAlchemy: Use a function to determine what results a query returns

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I want to use a function to determine the which rows are selected in a SQLAlchemy query. Here's the setup...

We have a basic SQLAlchemy mapped object:

```
class Foo(base):
    foo_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    foo_data = Column(String(255))
```

Now if we want to query all the table rows with a specific value for `foo_data`, we could do something like:

```
session.query(Foo).filter(Foo.foo_data == 'some data').all()
```

Now, I want the `Foo.foo_data == 'some data'` check to take place in a function... so our query looks like:

```
session.query(Foo).filter(check_foo(Foo.foo_data)).all()
```

Where `check_foo` looks like:

```
def check_foo(foo_data):
    if foo_data == 'foo':
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Is this type of thing possible? Obviously for this trivial case, it is really unnecessary, but for a more complex case this would be really useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [hybrid attributes](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/extensions/hybrid.html)

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_method

class Foo(base):
    foo_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    foo_data = Column(String(255))

    @hybrid_method
    def check_foo(self):
        return self.foo_data == 'foo'

    @check_foo.expression
    def check_foo(cls):
        return cls.foo_data == 'foo'

session.query(Foo).filter(Foo.check_foo()).all()
```